# Matching Elements From Arrays

Tags: ruby, set, matching

I have data structure like as below.

```
[{"league"=>:nba, "period"=>"h1","edge"=>-5.0, "home_team"=>"Cavaliers"},   
{"league"=>:nba, "period"=>"h1", "edge"=>-6.0, "home_team"=>"Pistons"}, 
{"league"=>:nba, "period"=>"h1", "edge"=>-6.0, "home_team"=>"Bucks"},   
{"league"=>:ncaab, "period"=>"h1", "edge"=>-7.0, "home_team"=>"Wisconsin"},   
{"league"=>:ncaab, "period"=>"h1", "edge"=>-7.0, "home_team"=>"Wisconsin"}]
```

I need to assign to each element in the array a new key/value pair, key = `"id"`, value = `x`, where `x` is an integer. The `x` should be the same for each element whose `"period"` and `"home_team"` values are the same, otherwise what `x` is doesn't matter. So the above  should result in something like this:

```
[{"league"=>:nba, "period"=>"h1","edge"=>-5.0, "home_team"=>"Cavaliers", "id"=>1},   
{"league"=>:nba, "period"=>"h1", "edge"=>-6.0, "home_team"=>"Pistons", "id"=>2},    
{"league"=>:nba, "period"=>"h1", "edge"=>-6.0, "home_team"=>"Bucks", "id"=>3},  
{"league"=>:ncaab, "period"=>"h1", "edge"=>-7.0, "home_team"=>"Wisconsin", "id"=>4},   
{"league"=>:ncaab, "period"=>"h1", "edge"=>-7.0, "home_team"=>"Wisconsin", "id"=>4}]
```

Comment: Your data structure is invalid.

Comment: now my data structure is valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a counting hash:

```
pair_ids = Hash.new { |_, pair| pair_ids[pair] = pair_ids.length }

items = [ 
  {"league"=>:nba, "period"=>"h1","edge"=>-5.0, "home_team"=>"Cavaliers"}   ,
  {"league"=>:nba, "period"=>"h1", "edge"=>-6.0, "home_team"=>"Pistons"}    ,
  {"league"=>:nba, "period"=>"h1", "edge"=>-6.0, "home_team"=>"Bucks"}   ,
  {"league"=>:ncaab, "period"=>"h1", "edge"=>-7.0, "home_team"=>"Wisconsin"}   ,
  {"league"=>:ncaab, "period"=>"h1", "edge"=>-7.0, "home_team"=>"Wisconsin"}
]

items.each do |item|
   item["id"] = pair_ids[ item.values_at("home_team", "period") ]
end

# now, items == [
#   {"league"=>:nba, "period"=>"h1", "edge"=>-5.0, "home_team"=>"Cavaliers", "id"=>0}, 
#   {"league"=>:nba, "period"=>"h1", "edge"=>-6.0, "home_team"=>"Pistons", "id"=>1}, 
#   {"league"=>:nba, "period"=>"h1", "edge"=>-6.0, "home_team"=>"Bucks", "id"=>2}, 
#   {"league"=>:ncaab, "period"=>"h1", "edge"=>-7.0, "home_team"=>"Wisconsin", "id"=>3}, 
#   {"league"=>:ncaab, "period"=>"h1", "edge"=>-7.0, "home_team"=>"Wisconsin", "id"=>3}
# ]
```

The `Hash.new` takes a block that is run for each lookup that doesn't match an existing key. We use that
block to cache a new id for each `home_team/period` pair.

Comment: It’s kind of weird to refer to the outer variable (`pair_ids`) in the `Hash.new` block instead of the reference to the hash it gives you (which you assigned to `_`).

Comment: I figured that would be easier for a novice to understand

Comment: That's very cool.  Perhaps I can offer a few words of explanation.  rampion is adding a key-value pair to each element of `items` while building the hash `pair_ids`. For the first `item` of `items`, let `k = item.values_at("home_team", "period") => ["Cavaliers", "h1"]`. `pair_ids` does not have this key `k` (it's empty), so `pairs_id(k)` is assigned `pairs_id.size`, which equals 0, and that is in turn assigned to `item["id"]`.  `pairs_id` is now `{["Cavaliers", "h1"]=>0})`...tbc

Comment: ...We now move on to the second element of `items`. `pairs_id` does not have the a key `["h1", "Pistons"]`, so `["h1", "Pistons"]=>1,` (since `pairs_id.size => 1`) is added to `pairs_id` and `item["id"]` => 1.  Similarly, `item["id"]=>2` is added to the third hash and `item["id"]=>3` to the fourth.  For the last  element of `items`, we search `pairs_id` for the key `["Wisconsin", "h1"]`.  As `pairs_id => { ["Cavaliers", "h1"]=>0, ["Pistons", "h1"]=>1, ["Bucks", "h1"]=>2, ["Wisconsin", "h1"]=>3 }, the key is found, so `item["id"]` is assigned `pairs_id[["Wisconsin", "h1"]]`, which equals 3.

Comment: Ah, I finally figured out that the block inside Hash.new{|x,y|} has x representing the hash itself, and y the key you pass it, I was assuming x,y is key,value pair.  Now I get it.  (reference, http://endofline.wordpress.com/2010/12/24/hash-tricks/)

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Enumerable#group_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

**Code**

```
def id_em(items)
  items.group_by { |h,i| [h["period"],h["home_team"]] }
       .map.with_index { |(_,v),i| v.map { |h| h.merge({id: i})} }
       .flatten
end
```

**Examples**

```
items = [{"league"=>:nba,   "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Cavaliers"},
         {"league"=>:nba,   "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Pistons"},
         {"league"=>:nba,   "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Bucks"},
         {"league"=>:ncaab, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Wisconsin"},
         {"league"=>:ncaab, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Wisconsin"}]

id_em(items)
  #=> [{"league"=>:nba,   "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Cavaliers", :id=>0},
  #    {"league"=>:nba,   "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Pistons",   :id=>1},
  #    {"league"=>:nba,   "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Bucks",     :id=>2},
  #    {"league"=>:ncaab, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Wisconsin", :id=>3},
  #    {"league"=>:ncaab, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Wisconsin", :id=>3}]

items = [{"league"=>:nba1, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Cavaliers"},
         {"league"=>:nba2, "period"=>"h2", "home_team"=>"Pistons"},
         {"league"=>:nba3, "period"=>"h2", "home_team"=>"Pistons"},
         {"league"=>:nba4, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Cavaliers"}]

p id_em(items)
  #=> [{"league"=>:nba1, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Cavaliers", :id=>0},
  #    {"league"=>:nba4, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Cavaliers", :id=>0},
  #    {"league"=>:nba2, "period"=>"h2", "home_team"=>"Pistons",   :id=>1},
  #    {"league"=>:nba3, "period"=>"h2", "home_team"=>"Pistons",   :id=>1}]
```

**Explanation**

For second example array `items` above:

```
a = items.group_by { |h,i| [h["period"],h["home_team"]] }
  #=> {["h1", "Cavaliers"] =>
  #      [{"league"=>:nba1, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Cavaliers"},
  #       {"league"=>:nba4, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Cavaliers"}],
  #    ["h2", "Pistons"]   =>
  #      [{"league"=>:nba2, "period"=>"h2", "home_team"=>"Pistons"},
  #       {"league"=>:nba3, "period"=>"h2", "home_team"=>"Pistons"}]}

b = a.map.with_index { |(_,v),i| v.map { |h| h.merge({id: i})} }
  #=> [[{"league"=>:nba1, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Cavaliers", :id=>0},
  #     {"league"=>:nba4, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Cavaliers", :id=>0}],
  #    [{"league"=>:nba2, "period"=>"h2", "home_team"=>"Pistons",   :id=>1},
  #     {"league"=>:nba3, "period"=>"h2", "home_team"=>"Pistons",   :id=>1}]]

b.flatten
  #=> [{"league"=>:nba1, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Cavaliers", :id=>0},
  #    {"league"=>:nba4, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Cavaliers", :id=>0},
  #    {"league"=>:nba2, "period"=>"h2", "home_team"=>"Pistons",   :id=>1},
  #    {"league"=>:nba3, "period"=>"h2", "home_team"=>"Pistons",   :id=>1}]
```

In calculating `b`, the first array passed to the block is assigned to the block variables given by

```
|(k,v),i|
```

as follows:

```
k = ["h1", "Cavaliers"]
v = [{"league"=>:nba1, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Cavaliers"},
     {"league"=>:nba4, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Cavaliers"}], 
i = 0
```

We will not use `k`, so have replaced it as a block variable with `_`.

`map` converts the first element of `v` to:

```
{"league"=>:nba1, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Cavaliers"}.merge({id: 0})
  #=> {"league"=>:nba1, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Cavaliers", :id=>0}
```

and the second element to:

```
{"league"=>:nba4, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Cavaliers"}.merge({id: 0})
  #=> {"league"=>:nba4, "period"=>"h1", "home_team"=>"Cavaliers", :id=>0}
```

Comment: elegant functional solution!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a hash code! I submitted two answers to this queston.  This one was an afterthought, but I prefer it to my other solution.  It makes use of the method ([Hash#hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-hash)).

**Code**

```
items.each{|h|h["id"]={"period"=>h["period"],"home_team"=>h["home_team"]}.hash}
```

**Example**

```
items = [{"league"=>:nba, "per"=>"h1", "ht"=>"Cavaliers"},
         {"league"=>:nba, "per"=>"h1", "ht"=>"Pistons"},
         {"league"=>:nba, "per"=>"h1", "ht"=>"Bucks"},
         {"league"=>:ncb, "per"=>"h1", "ht"=>"Wisconsin"},
         {"league"=>:ncb, "per"=>"h1", "ht"=>"Wisconsin"}]

items.each { |h| h["id"] = { "per" => h["per"], "ht" => h["ht"] }.hash }
#=>[{"league"=>:nba,"per"=>"h1","ht"=>"Cavaliers","id"=>-4168551181113196037},
#   {"league"=>:nba,"per"=>"h1","ht"=>"Pistons"  ,"id"=>-1923231267716315157},
#   {"league"=>:nba,"per"=>"h1","ht"=>"Bucks"    ,"id"=>-1538708673911299676},
#   {"league"=>:ncb,"per"=>"h1","ht"=>"Wisconsin","id"=> 377899609258784958},
#   {"league"=>:ncb,"per"=>"h1","ht"=>"Wisconsin","id"=> 377899609258784958}]
```